# How to up a counter if some condition is true in list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have this function:
locs is a list of locations: [(0,0),(4,5)...]
points is a list of values: [6,7,9...]

```
def foo(size,locs,points):
    matrix = []
    loc = 0
    rows = size[0]
    cols = size[1]
    for i in range(rows):
        row = []
        for j in range(cols):
            if ((i,j) in locs):
                row.append(points[loc])
                loc += 1
            else:  
                row.append(0)
        matrix.append(row)
    return matrix
```

It builds a matrix with 0s while inserting predefined points in the predefined location.
I want to turn it into list comprehension.
I have this:

```
loc = 0
rows = size[0]
cols = size[1]
matrix = [[points[loc] if (i,j) in locs else 0 for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
```

but I don't  know how to update the loc to be loc + 1 if condition is true.
I tried searching for this but couldn't find a result to try.
Will gladly accept ideas.
Thank you!

Comment: First, that doesn't sound like a job for a list comprehension. Looping over `zip(locs, points)` and inserting values directly into locations sounds like the way to go.

Comment: Second, the loop you're currently using may end up inserting a value at a different location from what you'd get by matching up locations and values in order. For example, `7` might not end up at location `(4, 5)`. Is that deliberate? It seems like a bug.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica What do you mean? The function? It works right for me.
What do you mean by looping over the zip?

Comment: [Here's an example](https://ideone.com/ryUwCS) of your `foo` mixing up points and values. `1` ends up at `(0, 0)` and `2` ends up at `(1, 1)`, when it looks like it should be the other way around.

Comment: oh.. Didn't think of it because my locations and points are ordered so it never happened to me. Will fix it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `NumPy` is an option, and since the task involves numerical matrix operations it does seems quite convenient, you have [`np.add.at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) to do exactly that:

```
a = np.zeros((rows, cols))
np.add.at(a, tuple(zip(*locs)), points)
```

Comment: `numpy.add.at` doesn't interpret its arguments the way you're thinking. You're setting values at the wrong locations.

Comment: Doesn't that list of tuples represent `x,y` coordinates? @user2357112supportsMonica

Comment: Oh actually your right, I need to unpack that list of tuples, duh @user2357112supportsMonica